# HgLab (Mercurial) on IIS7.5. Http error 500 Access denied when pushing

Tags: python, mercurial, iis-7.5

I am trying to Setup Mercurial on IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2 Standard SP1 64bit.
At first we installed it on a Win 7 machine 32bit with no problem , but moved it to the live server and got user permission issue.
TortoiseHg give teh following error when I Push.

HTTP Error: 500 (Access to the path 'C:\Apps\hglab\Repos\data\repositories\master\CashExpress\Kenya.hg\store\00changelog.i' is denied.)

I had to activate 32bit apps on the 2008 R2 webserver.
I am using HgLab 0.3.10 and TortoiseHg 2.9.2
I am using the Mercurial I downloaded from this site http://hglabhq.com/

I searched the web extensively and also Stack overflow. Most solutions are not for IIS7.5 and those that are for IIS7.5 does not address my problem.

I think it is a user permission issue or 32bit/64bit. Not sure what the user is that Mercurial uses.
I tried grating the anonymous IUSR full access, but no success.
I check the IIS logs and it looks like it is using user "mecurial/proto1.0" which I can't get any information on. I also can't find that user on windows. I presume it is a Python/Apatch user.

If you need any more information I will get it for you.

I am not that familiar with Python or Apache.

I want to use Mecurial and not TFS.

Comment: You should consider to improve and shorten the title of the question.